# How to incorporate a slash '/' into a Ruby symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you use a slash `/` in a Ruby symbol? I'm trying to use symbols to express file names instead of strings but I can't figure out how to reference two levels of a file's path using a symbol. For example, how would you express `articles/show` as a Ruby symbol?

Comment: Why are you trying to use symbols for paths? That seems a bit strange.

Comment: I don't think there's anything to be gained by it.  Most libraries that do anything with the filename will probably implicitly convert it back to a string.   Using symbols for this purpose is not idiomatic ruby, and just looks odd.

Comment: Don't do this. It's a fast path to confusing and unmaintainable code. Use strings, or the Pathname class. None of the IO or File class take strings; are you going to rewrite those classes?

Comment: "Most libraries that do anything with the filename will probably implicitly convert it back to a string." Actually not. IO and File methods will puke.

Comment: I agree that Symbols should probably not be used in this way, and the answers should reflect that. But that does not mean that this is not a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a string to a symbol using `to_sym`:

```
'a/b'.to_sym # => :"a/b"
```

however, just because you can do that, doesn't mean you *should* do it. There are reasons we use symbols, such as for memory savings and a little bit faster lookups, but there are times the savings don't outweigh the problems they introduce, such as when trying to work with them as filenames.

The question really seems like an "[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)", which means you're asking about "Y" but really need to work on "X".

In normal scripts, we might need to open a handful of files, meaning there's only a handful of strings required, and symbols will hardly help save space over the string versions. If you're reading a lot of files, you shouldn't be defining them in your code but instead be storing the names in a separate file, and iterate over that file, retrieving the name of a file then process it, one-by-one.

The IO class doesn't expect symbols. Running:

```
puts File.foreach('test.txt'.to_sym).to_a
```

results in:

```
`foreach': no implicit conversion of Symbol into String (TypeError)
```

That's not a good sign, and means that, to use symbols instead of strings, you'd have to either reimplement all the IO methods or convert to strings on the fly.

It also means that the convenience methods, just as `join`, won't work. Where normally we can do:

```
File.join('a', 'b') # => "a/b"
```

Passing in symbols results in:

```
File.join(:a, :b) # => 
# ~> -:2:in `join': no implicit conversion of Symbol into String (TypeError)
# ~>  from -:2:in `<main>'
```

and using something like:

```
File.join(:a.to_s, :b.to_s).to_sym # => :"a/b"
```

seems like a real waste of typing and CPU time that will only compound the problem the further that it is used.

Answer (score 3):

```
:'articles/show'
```

Lot's more info at http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm